# Moving DIV content of an external html to Div of another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 html files. Index.html invokes chat.html. Chat.html body contains a DIV which I want to populate with Div of a third HTML file (star.html) which resides in the same folder as chat.html.

chat.html -

```html
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Chat - Group Menu</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <!-- Begin page content -->
            <div class="container" id="chatDiv">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h1>Mobile Layout</h1>
                </div>
                <p class="lead">Chat stuff to appear here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="testDIV"></div>
        <div id="footer">
             //some DIV content here
        </div>
</body>
```

star.html -

```html
<body>
    <p> hello all </p>
</body>
```

jquery code I am using (in an external .js file) is -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#stars").click(function() {
                alert("change DIV to show STAR stuff");
                $("#testDIV").load('star.html');
            });
        });
```

Here, the alert is displayed. But the content is not moving to chat.html Div.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is the `#stars` element that you click?

Comment: Also, how are you loading `chat.html`?

Comment: "stars" is an id for an image that I click. It us in the footer DIV of the chat.html file above. This navigation tab has 3 images. The second image is stars. The code for that is as below.                                           
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a id="stars" href="#">
                        <img id="starImg" src='../img/feature3.png' alt='missing'>
                        <div class="caption">Stars</div>
                    </a>
                </div>

Comment: index.html has logon button. On click of that button, I do validations. It validations are successful, I call chat.html page. The code is $('#loginBtn').click(function() {
    //    $(this).validateEmail();
    //    $(this).validatePassword();
    window.open("html/chat.html");
});

Comment: Guys, anyone who can help? I am stuck up with this since yesterday and there seems to be no respite.

Comment: did you see my updated answer, i separated the click events

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how you are opening a new window for chat, you need to address that window in order to manipulate that DOM. You may also need to add jQuery to the chat.html page if you haven't already

```
    $('#loginBtn').click(function() {
      $(this).validateEmail(); 
      $(this).validatePassword(); 
      var window.popup =  window.open("html/chat.html"); 
    });

 $("#stars").click(function() {
     alert("change DIV to show STAR stuff");
     window.popup.document.$("#testDIV").load('star.html');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to keep the clicks separate as they have a lot of functionaility specific to each image click. I still tried to see if it worked based on your suggestions. It did not, unfortunately.

Comment: in that case, you just need to make the `popup` variable global, i edited my answer to reflect this change, I simply set it to the `window` object